# Python: Urllib2 returns 404

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm trying to read some content from a URL using python but am getting a 404 every time I try.

Here is my test code, and the offending URL:

```
url = 'http://supercoach.heraldsun.com.au'

headers = {"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
try:
   handle = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except IOError, e:
    print e.code
```

The site works fine in a browser, and I have previously had no issues with this script, but a recent update to the site has caused it to fail.

I've tried adding a user agent header as similar questions have that as a suggestion.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Thanks
JP

Comment: @Ruben, so you are getting 303? Is that determined by running the above code? I am definitely getting 404, but perhaps it is a system specific thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `requests` which provides a friendly wrapper around the libraries in Python; and it [handles redirection for you](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history).

Your code with requests is simply:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://supercoach.heraldsun.com.au')
```

Comment: Thanks Burhan, however cannot currently install packages where I am

Comment: You can just download it and keep it in the same directory as your other file; you only install packages when you want them available system wide (or if they offer any command line utilities/helpers).

Comment: `urllib2` can follow redirects. Your code produces `TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.`

Comment: It can (of course), I just meant that requests doesn't require that much code to get it done. requests uses urllib and others under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set cookies and increase number of allowed redirections:

```
import urllib2
from cookielib import CookieJar

class RedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    max_repeats = 100
    max_redirections = 1000

    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        print code
        print headers
        return urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_302(
            self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)
    http_error_300 = http_error_302
    http_error_301 = http_error_302
    http_error_303 = http_error_302
    http_error_307 = http_error_302

cookiejar = CookieJar()
urlopen = urllib2.build_opener(RedirectHandler(),
                               urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar)).open
request = urllib2.Request('http://supercoach.heraldsun.com.au',
                          headers={"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
response = urlopen(request)
print '*' * 60
print response.info()
print response.read()
response.close()
```